# NUC6CAYH Ubuntu 16.04 sound interesting problem

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi, vlc

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server on NUC6CAYH.

```
uname -a
Linux UNUC 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Today I found that when I run Firefox and video on page first of all after reboot

http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/ivysilani/12059685760-co-nase-babicky-umely-a-na-co-my-jsme-zapomneli/217562220460006-zeli/

and after I can play music or video in VLC player with sound on my HDMI Samsung TV

But if I first run video with VLC player Ubuntu cannot sound nothing.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: there was problem with kernel version now i use 4.18.0-041800-generic an i have sound and also wifi